# How to get percentage of sales

Tags: python, python-3.3

```
print("Profit Predition.")

sales=input("Enter amount of sales: ")

print('Total sales: ', sales)

profit=sales* 0.21

print(format(profit, ',.2'))
```

The results I am getting for the last line should be (using an input of `974.58`, which is just the example used):

```
Profit Prediction.
Enter amount of sales: 974.58
Total sales: 974.58
Expected profit: 204.66
```

but instead of the last line what I am getting is `2e+02`. I can't figure out how to make it return a "float" number. I'm very new to programming and would appreciate the help! The version of python that I am using is 3.3.5

Answer (score 2):

UPDATE: I am so sorry for the mistakes I have made. I have updated my answer.

So try to replace the last line with:

```
print('%.2f' % profit)
```

or

```
print("{0:.2f}".format(profit))
```

And you can get the right thing.

Comment: Should that `%` be a `,`? Otherwise, your sample code doesn't really match what you say in the first paragraph (and the format is useless?).

Comment: Jerry, I wasn't expecting you to be so apologetic, fixing the answer (if indeed my comment was even correct) would have been more than enough. Cheers and +1.

Comment: @paxdiablo Thanks for your support.. I just hope I haven't misled others ;)

Answer (score 1):

I always use `print` in this way:

```
print("%.2f" % profit)
```

Comment: Doesn't that rather screw up your integers and strings? And what if the variable you're trying to print isn't called `profit`? :-)

Comment: The OP asked for a float number and a variable called profit.

Comment: It's humour, skytux, you said you _always_ use `print` that way. Man does no-one even _see_ the smileys nowadays?

Comment: Yes, I see it now hahaha... :-)

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
print("{:,.2f}".format(profit))
```

For the detail, please refer to https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings.